# Finding the maximum out of three doubles from standard input

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

We have a java assignment where in we're supposed to develop a method that scans one line that is supposed to contain three double values and returns the largest. Throwing all possible exceptions is allowed.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class s3dv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double entered;
        System.out.println("Enter 3 values to find the maximum:");
        entered = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Maximum is - " + getMaxValue(entered));
    }

    //Find maximum (largest) value in array using loop  
    public static double getMaxValue(double[] numbers){  
        double maxValue = numbers[0];  
        for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){  
            if(numbers[i] > maxValue){  
                maxValue = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;  
    }  // End getMaxValue method
}
```

I'm having an error at line 15.

Comment: What's the error you're getting exactly?

Comment: You're passing in a double to getMaxValue which is expecting an array of doubles...

Comment: input.nextDouble() does not return array. You need to fix that

Comment: Should you tag this as homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] entered = new double[3]; 
    System.out.println("Enter 3 values to find the maximum:");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    entered[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum is - " + getMaxValue(entered)); 
}

//Find maximum (largest) value in array using loop
public static double getMaxValue(double[] numbers){
double maxValue = numbers[0];
for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
if(numbers[i] > maxValue){
maxValue = numbers[i]; } } return maxValue;

}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the for loop start at 0?

Comment: No, because the 0th element is already stored in variable maxValue.

Comment: Did you able to recognize where was your mistake?

Comment: @deporter What I mean is that I should only prompt the question only once and not make the question loop 3x.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give a double parameter to a method while it expects a double array. And also you request user to enter double value only once, you should repeat that procedure. Change your main method to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] entered = new double[3];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter != 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a double value:");
        entered[counter++] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum is - " + getMaxValue(entered));
}
```

Your `getMaxValue()` method seems OK, however when entering doubles from console use *comma(,)* instead of *dot(.)*, you might get `InputMismatchException` otherwise.

Comment: I'm not allowed to loop the question.

Answer (score 0):

this main code will read the 3 double value in a single line, split them and pass it to the getMaxValue

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userLine, lineSplitted[];

        System.out.println("Enter 3 values to find the maximum:");
        userLine = input.nextLine();
        lineSplitted=userLine.split(" ");

        double entered[]=new double[lineSplitted.length];
        for (int i=0; i<lineSplitted.length; i++) entered[i]=Double.valueOf(lineSplitted[i]);

        System.out.println("Maximum is - " + getMaxValue(entered));
    }
```